# How to find the variance of a subset of the data in r?

Tags: r, subset, boxplot, variance, hypothesis-test

I’m trying to find the variance of a subset of the whole data (dat) “pollutionData.csv”.

I want the variance of the PM2.5 levels when rain = 0.

```
var(PM2.5, data=subset(dat, RAIN == 0))
```

The code above isn’t working.

```
aggregate(dat[, 6], list(dat$RAIN==0), var, na.rm=TRUE)
```

The code above outputs the variance when the rain = 0 and when rain > 0, but I want to do a hypothesis test for the variances so this isn’t helpful.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the 'PM2.5' where 'RAIN' is 0 and then take the `var`

```
with(dat, var(PM2.5[RAIN == 0], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Another option is to  `replace` the values in 'PM2.5 where 'RAIN' is 0 with `NA` and then apply `var`

```
with(dat, var(replace(PM2.5,  RAIN == 0, NA), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

`aggregate` is required when we want a group by operation.  Here, we are only getting the `var` of the 'PM2.5` where the 'RAIN' is 0